# ejabberd clustering, Slave doesn't work when master goes down

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I have setup ejabberd clustering, one is master and other is slave as described [here](http://chadillac.tumblr.com/post/35967173942/easy-ejabberd-clustering-guide-mnesia-mysql).

I have copied .erlang.cookie and database files from master to slave.
Everything is working fine.
The issue is when I stop master node:

1. Then no request getting routed to slave.
2. When trying to restart slave node its not getting start once it down.

I get stuck here, please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the standard behaviour of Mnesia. If the node you start was not the last one that was stopped in a cluster, then it does not have any way to know if it has the latest, most up to date data.

The process to start a Mnesia cluster is to start the node in reverse order in which they were shutdown.

In case the node that was last seen on Mnesia cluster cannot start or join the cluster, them you need to use a Mnesia command to force the cluster "master", that is tell it that you consider this node has the most up to date content. This is done by using Erlang command [mnesia:set_master_nodes/1](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#set_master_nodes-1).

For example, from ejabberd Erlang command-line:

```
mnesia:set_master_nodes([node1@myhost]).
```

In most case, Mnesia clustering handles everything automatically. When a node goes down, the other nodes are aware and automatically keep on working transparently. The only case you need to set which node as the reference data (with `set_master_nodes/1`), is when this is ambiguous for Mnesia, that is either when starting only nodes that were down when there was still running nodes or when there is a netsplit.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but what happened when master and slave both are running simultaneously and master goes down. In this case slave should work right?

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of clustering. Mnesia is multimaster. There is no real master, but it need to protect consistency of data and make sure it will not destroy the data. When one node goes down, there is no consistency issue for the remaining node.

Comment: Thanks Mickael, got that. When one node to goes down, the remain node need to set as master, because there is no consistency issue for remaining node. It will work independently.

Comment: No, the remain node does not need to be manually set as master. This is handled automatically by Erlang / Mnesia. The only case when you need to set master manually is when there is an ambiguity about which node as the reference data.

Comment: Do you have a load balancer in front ? You need to route the traffic properly of course. And again: There is no master / slave concept in ejabberd. Mnesia and this ejabberd is multi masters.

Comment: Yes, we have load balancer in front. checking the things with team. Thanks

Comment: If you have no traffic coming to second node, it must be a load balancer issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the step from below link:
 http://chadillac.tumblr.com/post/35967173942/easy-ejabberd-clustering-guide-mnesia-mysql
and call the method join_as_master(NodeName) of the  easy_cluster module.

Comment: Be careful. You have to make sure of what you do when forcing master data set, otherwise it can lead to data loss.

Comment: Ok i used this command.              mnesia:set_master_nodes([node1@myhost]).                                   thanks a lot