# ejabberd Clustering with master Slave and Master Master not avoid single point of failure

Tags: ejabberd

Whenever Master gets down in ejabberd Cluster slave will not be able to process request. i follow the tutorial from : ***http://chadillac.tumblr.com/post/35967173942/easy-ejabberd-clustering-guide-mnesia-mysql*** and try with join_node() and join_as_master() also. But its not working. My cluster is working and **i used mysql database as separate database for both node.** I tried also with join as master slave and master master method. Both not working to avoid single point of fauilure. **Is it necessary to synchronize slave and master mnesia database?** please any one can help me in this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ejabberd clustering, Slave doesn't work when master goes down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715119/ejabberd-clustering-slave-doesnt-work-when-master-goes-down)

Answer (score 1):

There is no single point of failure with ejabberd if you configure it the right way. There is no such thing as master-slave in ejabberd. ejabberd is master-master and if you configure it with `join_cluster`command as described in official ejabberd documentation: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/clustering/

You need to configure the other services as redundant as well:
- Load balancer
- MySQL

Once done, I do not see what you can see as point of failure. If a node has to go down, the service keeps on working fine for users connected on other nodes and the one that have been disconnected can reconnect just fine on any of the remaining node.

If you means that if you stop both nodes and then try to start only the first stopped, this is normal behaviour of Mnesia distributed database. It is then a duplicate question already answered here: [ejabberd clustering, Slave doesn't work when master goes down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715119/ejabberd-clustering-slave-doesnt-work-when-master-goes-down/34716860#34716860)

*Note: The blog post you are pointing to is obsolete.*

Comment: Thank you  for answering my question ...i follow the whole document and setup ejabberd cluster on AWS. 2 nodes i.e. node1 and node 2 got connected  in cluster and it also shows in web portal. The issue is as i down node 2, whole cluster is working fine. But whenever i down node 1, whole cluster stop working. After again up node1, both nodes remain in cluster. The main problem is to maintain cluster working whenever i down node 1.

Comment: As ejabberd does not have any master, if any node goes down, service will keep on working. If this is not the case, you got your config wrong. To get further help, you need to be more specific about "whole cluster stop working". What do you mean ? What are the symptoms ? What are in the logs ? etc

Comment: ya sir i refer  your suggested documentation from official website. Now what i have done is as per documentation: ya sir i refer  your suggested documentation from official website.  i set cluster on ejabberd1 and ejabberd2 node. i put the ejabberd.yml file same on both node and change the erlangnode option in ejabberdctl.cfg file. erlangcookie file has same content. and in /etc/hosts of ejabberd 1 mentioned address of ejabberd1.  continue.........................

Comment: In /etc/hosts  of ejabberd 2 mentioned ip address of ejabberd 1 and ejabbberd 2 both. As per your documentation, run command   

$ ejabberdctl join_cluster 'ejabberd@ejabberd01'
 and finally cluster is completed. It shows everything and both node serving request. but when i down ejabberd 2, still  ejabberd 1 working  fine. But as soon as i down ejabberd 1, then everything gone. i used ejabberd 15.09 version. I also tried this with ejabberd 16.01. please give me any blog reference or tell me where m i doing any wrong config?

Comment: What you are saying is that you have two nodes, are shutting node 2 all is fine and then shutting node 1 and all stop working. It seems normal. If you have two nodes and shut down both of them you have no service. If what you mean is that if you start node 2 after having shutting down node 1 it wait before serving request, this is a duplicate question, answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715119/ejabberd-clustering-slave-doesnt-work-when-master-goes-down/34716860#34716860

Comment: ok now understood scenario. In my case i am setting ejabberd cluster on AWS Cloud.  just confused what should be in the host field of ejabberd.yml and erlang_node field in ejabberdctl.cfg. Also not sure about what will be the  values in /etc/hosts  file.